# What decides who awake?

Tags: lore, world-of-darkness, mage-the-ascension

I have had a discussion that Hikikomori (modern day hermits that have no psychological disorder and do not leave the house of there parents because they do not want to face society and there overburdening expectations) would never be Mages because it is said that who never leaves the house will never awake. Now I am curious, is there somewhere an explanation about who will get the gift of magick or is this never explained?

Comment: As I said, I had a discussion with another person and he said, that those reclusives will never awake because for it, it is needed to leave the house but as a source he said somewhere in the MtA Books.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Mage: The Ascension sourcebook identifies that everyone has a spark of potential, and anyone who realizes or activates that potential awakens.  The book places no limits on who can awaken or what they must do to awaken.  **Everyone has the spark of potential.  Anyone can awaken by realizing that potential.**  The exact process is not defined because every sleeper has their own journey by which they awaken.

Mages can awaken without interacting with others.  The Akashic Brotherhood sourcebook identifies mountain-dwelling hermits in Japan as such awakened individuals.  The Technocracy sourcebook identifies certain awakened individuals who spend their entire lives on the internet and at their computer.  Other traditions also include hermits, but these two are polar opposite styles and the other lie somewhere in-between.

Modern-day hermits are no different.  Being a member of your immediate society is not a requirement for a sleeper to awaken.  Interacting with some form of society to hone the use of magic would be required, however.  If they never participate in any formal training, leave the confines of their houses to learn more about their abilities, or contact other more knowledgeable people to learn about what they are, then they will not achieve a strong mastery over their abilities.

Akashic hermits connected to each other using their mastery of the Mind sphere to send each other visions and astrally project.  During their meditation, they communicated (either knowingly or unknowingly) with their brethren.  Based in this, it is my interpretation that a modern Akashic monk could employ any meditation technique like Buddhist mantra saying, tai-chi, or even gardening to achieve the tranquil mind-state necessary to commune mentally.

A technological-paradigm hermit can still use online communication.  This communication may have been embedded with Arcane patterns to make sleepers less able to perceive it.  Technocratic-paradigm hermits could ignore their immediately adjacent society and be a part of whichever online network they choose, likely with the Technocracy locating them to join their ranks officially.

Comment: So a Virtual Adept would be for a Hikikomori viable?

Comment: I cannot judge if your character is viable.  You haven't nearly given enough information about how your character works nor about the story they're going to take part in.  You need to have a discussion with your storyteller if how you envision your hermit being a virtual adept works with the story they want to tell.  They eventually will have to leave the house to take part in the campaign, so you'll need to work with your storyteller to work out the details of your concept.

Comment: It whas meant if it is possible. Well the GM whas not really opposed to the idea, we just did not want to have a lore break if there whas something that would contradict it. Thank you very much for your help